# Long respond time when getting data from API with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance

I'm working on Mac with a local environment. I own all the APIs.

I have a web page that does an ajax call to API.
(e.g. http://1.api.loc/v1.0/getSomthing?id=1)
This API is coded in PHP. API 1 does another call to Api 2.(http://2.api.loc/v1.0/getSomthingSpecific?id=1)

This second call is done using curl in PHP.
I had the same result using `file_get_content()` even with this fix ([add context header](http://moffe42.blogspot.fr/2010/10/filegetcontents-acting-very-slow.html))

Then, my JS code (Jquery) receives the result, parses it and populates a table in my HTML page.

The first problem I had was that, when I call directly Api2 (over a web browser), the result shows up in 200ms. When I call Api1 (which call Api 2) the result shows up in 35 seconds. After some investigation, I found out that the DNSLookup was very slow. I fixed this changing my `/etc/hosts` configuration.

Now both APIs works well and responds within few ms (when called directly on web browser or curl command line). The problem is in my JS code. when I do my ajax call, it takes +30 seconds to get a response.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://1.api.loc/v1.0/getSomething",
    data:{'id' : 1},
    success: function (data) {
        handler(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show us the code of the jquery that creates the table. As well as the api?

Comment: use chrome developer tools to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the external API asynchronously is the best bet.

When it is part of a user's process, it is best to show feedback that the call is underway and some indication whether the call finished and succeeded or failed once you get response. If possible, let the user give other input while waiting for feedback on the external API, this negates the "slow and painful" feeling.

Comment: it's not really the purpose. I already have what you are talking about. The Api doesn't take too long to respond...

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer.
Actually, the Api 1 respond with a JSON format, and Api2 just echoed the respond with no specific header. and this is the point !

adding this before echoing the results fixed the bug :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

thank's to all for your help